# Site Title Not Showing Up in Sites Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, site-collection, modern-experience, hub-site

I have a weird issue showing up on my tenant. I have a hub site (newly created) called Project Hub and I associated a new site collection (called Issue Tracking System) with this hub site. I am using the Sites web part to show the associated site. I use the selection option, "All sites in the hub", and I see the 1 associated site. However, the title of the site does not show up. It comes through as 'Home' (screenshot below).

[image]

The weird thing here is, if I change the selection option as "Select sites", I can see the site before selecting (the name appears as 'Home' with the checkbox), the site's true name appears (as expected).

[image]

[image]

I definitely think this is a bug, but wanted to see if anyone else has come across this issue and raised it with Microsoft.

Thank you

Comment: An interesting thing I did find. When I looked at the dev tools, network tab, to see what the http request for this item is, I saw the site title returned is "Home":

...."Title":"Home","Type":"Site"}...

Also, the acronym returned is "H":

...."Acronym":"H"...

The site name in SharePoint admin is definitely not Home so I have no idea where this value is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue per my test.

When I change options from **All sites in the hub** to **Select sites**, 0 sites selected as default, and the site title shows correctly both in selection and web parts.

Please try to remove the association with the hub site then associate the site back with the same Hub site to compare the result.

Comment: I tried that, but it didnt work. I still get the same result as above. It's really weird. I am wondering if its an issue with my tenant?

Comment: I suggest you create a new hub site to test again, if the issue still exists, you could raise a new support request with Microsoft.